# Syntax error with datepicker in php and js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Well hello there. I have this problem where I can't figure out where the syntax error is with my dateTimePicker. please help here is the form its in

```
<form name="subExpdate" method="POST" action="" id="subExpdate" >
                            <input type="date" id="expDatePicker" name="expDatePicker" style="margin-bottom: 5px" >
                            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $prodLink->valueof('link_id') ?>" id="hidID" name="hidID">
                            <input type="hidden" name="prodInt" id="prodInt" value="<?php echo $selInterface; ?>"/>
                            <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" name="changeExpireDate" id="changeExpireDate" onclick="changeExpireDate23()" >Change expire date</button>
                        </form>
```

Here is my function:

```
function changeExpireDate23() {
        var expTime = new FormData(document.getElementById('subExpdate'));
        console.log('something' + expTime);
        $.ajax({
        url: "my path and it works not allowed to show",
                type: 'POST',
                data:expTime,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false, 
                success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                        console.log(data);
                }
    });
    }
```

and here is my ajax page :

```
 if (isset($_POST['expDatePicker'])){
            $datePicker = date('d/m/Y  H:i:s' , strtotime($_POST['expDatePicker']));
            $getLinkData = new CGenRs("SELECT * FROM lu_product_link WHERE link_id = '" . $hidid . "' ", $cao_beta2);
            $getLinkData->first();

            $updateExpDate = "UPDATE lu_product_link SET (link_promo_expiry) = '".$datePicker."' WHERE link_id = '".$hidid."'";
            if($cao_beta2->execute($updateExpDate)){
                echo 'SUCCESS date updated';
            } else{
                echo 'Failed sorry mate';
            }
```

please if you can help me it would be much appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: You should check this line `contentType: false,  1.6+)`

Comment: Forgot to mention the syntax error comes from the ajax sorry

Comment: how do I edit that was part of the comments in the code I took out the comments but not all of that comment hahah lol sorry

Comment: did you forgot to paste `}` for `if (isset($_POST['expDatePicker'])){` ?

Comment: nope it works now I saw that my coloum name was in brackets. Must not be in brackets

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem it was this line

```
$updateExpDate = "UPDATE lu_product_link SET (link_promo_expiry) = '".$datePicker."' WHERE link_id = '".$hidid."'";
```

The (link_promo_expiry) should not have been in ()